# Calling back 2 times with the same argument

Tags: c#, function, interface, callback, call

I came across this C# code during a code review. Somehow it seems to be odd calling back 2 times with the same argument (inside the catch).

```
public interface IMyExceptionHandler
{
    void Handle_1(Exception ex);

    void Handle_2(Exception ex);
}

public class SpecialException : Exception {}

public class MyBusinessLogic
{
    private readonly IMyExceptionHandler _handler;

    public MyBusinessLogic(IMyExceptionHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public void DoMagic()
    {
        try
        {
            // ommitted.
        }
        catch (SpecialException ex)
        {
            _handler.Handle_1(ex);
            _handler.Handle_2(ex);

            // 3rd way to handle ex somehow.
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any good reasons not to enhance the interface with a more special handling method?

Comment: This depends on your methods and needs - theres no "common sense" answer to this question

Comment: must be on CodeReview Site

Comment: My guess is that `Handle_1` and `Handle_2` do 2 different things.

Comment: Well they do 2 different things. What I wanted to know is why not wrapping those to callbacks inside the implemenation of another 3rd interface method?